# Oracle SQL - Keep Top 100 Highest Counts

Tags: sql, oracle, count, limit

My task is to keep only 100 largest clients in the output, so I need to count number of IDs per customer, and then keep only top 100. The output should contain all the necessary variables, no groupings.

Sample output would look like:

```
Var1, Var2, ID
aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb, 12345
ccccccc, ddddddd, 12345
...
eeeeeee, fffffff, 67890
```

Please find my best attempt so far (I am struggling with the limit part for this query):

```
SELECT 

A.Var1,
P.Var2, 
P.ID

FROM Database1 P

INNER JOIN Database2 A
ON P.ID = A.ID

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS IDs_per_BAN

FROM Database1 

GROUP BY ID 
) NUM_COUNT
ON P.ID = NUM_COUNT.ID

WHERE

(
???
)

ORDER BY NUM_COUNT.IDs_per_BAN DESC
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: your schema is not clear... please share it or a simplified but equivalent version